# Error in storing property name as url in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

How to store the following document in mongo, I'm getting below error while inserting .

Document :

```
{
    "data": {
        "http://test.abc.com/xyz/xyz/displayname": "my Name"
    }
}
```

ERROR :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name http://test.abc.com/xyz/xyz/displayname
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:494)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:188)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:172)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:189)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:131)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Restrictions on field names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

> Field names cannot contain the null character.
>
> Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
>
> Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of field names that contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

Rather, you can store two fields. One for URI and another for name.